Thread safe Dictionary with items usage count and auto clean
How to implement thread safe auto clean Dictionary?
EventBusManager must provide an EventBus instance per roomId.
EventBusManager usage:
// When user connect to room
var eventBus = evtBusManager.GetIncrementUsage(roomId);

// When user disconnect
evtBusManager.DecrementUsage(roomId);

EventBusManager implementation:
public class EventBusManager {
    readonly Dictionary<string, BusUsage> buses = [];

    public EventBus GetIncrementUsage(string roomId) {
        lock (buses) {
            if (!buses.TryGetValue(roomId, out var busUsage)) {
                busUsage = new BusUsage(new EventBus());
                buses.Add(roomId, busUsage);
                return busUsage.Bus;
            }

            busUsage.UsageCount++;
            return busUsage.Bus;
        }
    }

    public void DecrementUsage(string roomId) {
        lock (buses) {
            if (!buses.TryGetValue(roomId, out var busUsage))
                return;

            busUsage.UsageCount--;

            if (busUsage.UsageCount == 0)
                buses.Remove(roomId);
        }
    }

    record BusUsage(EventBus Bus) {
        public int UsageCount = 1;
    };
}

Is the implementation thread safe?

This looks to be thread-safe as long as no external code not shown ever changes the UsageCount field; any such access could lead to undefined outcomes. The lock will work fine; it could perhaps be rewritten using a concurrent dictionary and interlocked mutate, but that's a lot more different code paths to consider; there's a lot to be said for the simplicity of a lock

Consider using code-review.

Why do you need to implement new one? Does ConcurrentDictionary class not good enough? If you need some more functionality you can wrap it inside your one class.

@maximelian1986 The OP would need locking beyond that provided by ConcurrentDictionary due to the requirement for the incrementing/decrementing of UsageCount. The incrementing/decrementing of that along with potential adding/removing an item from the dictionary requires an atomic operation, which in this case is best provided by the use of lock.

Is this the complete API and implementation of the EventBusManager class? It looks strange because the information stored in the dictionary is not exposed in any way. Please declare the buses field as private, to make it clear that no external code is using it. Or make it clear that the buses is exposed by adding a properly named public property that exposes it: public Dictionary<string, BusUsage> Buses => buses; Please note that the naming convention for private fields is to start with an underscore. _buses is the conventional/expected name.

@TheodorZoulias the information stored in the dictionary is exposed via GetIncrementUsage(roomId) method

Ah, sorry, I didn't notice the return type of GetIncrementUsage. But as I see now the GetIncrementUsage returns the EventBus, not the BusUsage that contains the UsageCount. I guess that the UsageCount needs not to be exposed, because it is used only for evicting unused entries from the dictionary. Could you edit the question and declare the buses field and the BusUsage record as private, to make it clear that they are not intended to be exposed?

Regarding the EventBus type, is it an immutable class? If not, is it mutated by multiple threads without synchronization? If so, is it thread-safe?

Basically, it looks like functionally thread-safe, but there is one strategic mistake in your code. You should not use the field buses as a lock object. The idiomatic technique is this:
public class EventBusManager {       
    //...
    public EventBus GetIncrementUsage(string roomId) {
        lock (lockObject) {
            //...
            return busUsage.Bus;
        }
    }
    public void DecrementUsage(string roomId) {
        lock (lockObject) {
            //...
        }
    }
    object lockObject = new();
    // System.Threading.Lock lockObject = new(); // for .NET 9 and up
}

Note that the field lockObject should always be private.
You can find some rationale behind that here. The specifically stated point is that a lock object should be an instance not used for any other purpose.
There is another issue, a minor one: UsageCount should not be public. I understand that it is not private because you want to access it outside BusUsage in the scope of EventBusManager, but for this purpose, internale access would suffice.
